# Globe Builder halo not exporting to image or showing on layout QGIS 3.30.1

Tags: qgis, globe

I'm using the Globe Builder plugin, halo is looking fine in the map window but not showing on layout or when I export image from project. I don't really want to use layout, export to image would be enough. Why the halo not showing tho? How can I create a halo myself for the globe?

See examples:
[image]

[image]